# Sufficient condition for $E(wu\mid v)=0$ given that $E(u\mid v)=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to figure out what condition concerning $w$ and $v$ would be enough for me to infer that $E(wu\mid v)=0$ given that I already know $E(u\mid v)=0$.

Clearly, $w$ is a constant works: $E(wu\mid v)=wE(u\mid v)=0$. But I'm trying to find a weaker condition. I'm contemplating $w$ and $u$ are independent. I write
$$
E(wu\mid v)=E[E(wu\mid w,v)\mid v]=E[wE(u\mid w,v)\mid v]=E[wE(u\mid v)\mid v]=E[w0\mid v]=0.
$$
Does it seem correct to you? Can you suggest some other sufficient conditions?

Comment: The _conditional_ covariance of $W$ and $U$ given that the random variable $V$ has value $v$ is
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(W, U\mid V = v)
&= E[WU\mid V=v] - E[W\mid V=v]E[U \mid V = v]\\
&= E[WU\mid V=v] - E[W\mid V=v]\times 0\\
&= E[WU\mid V=v].
\end{align}
Thus, independence might not be needed; it would suffice if $W$ and $U$
were conditionally uncorrelated random variables given $V$.

Comment: otherwise your calculation is correct.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Good observation. Can you think of a stronger condition on $w$ and $u$ (but weaker than independence)? While you're correct, $\text{Cov}(wu|v)=0$ is too "close" to $E(wu|v)=0$ to be informative. (In fact, you have shown $E(wu|v)=0$ iff $\text{Cov}(wu|v)=0$.) Thanks to user190080 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is correct. This can be generalized a little bit more: if $w$ can be written as $w'f(v)$, where $f\colon\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$ is Borel measurable and $w'$ is independent of $u$, then $\mathbb E[wu\mid v]=0$. Indeed, 
$$\mathbb E[wu\mid v]=f(v)\mathbb E[w'u\mid v]=0$$
by the reasoning in the opening post.